# Can I put JS and CSS outside the public folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I put my JS and CSS files outside the public folder? I have a library that I'd like all my websites to use and for easy updating, have this outside a particular website public folder so it can be easily read by all. Is this possible or do I need to host it all on another domain (I'd rather not for ease).

htaccess possibly?

Comment: I agree with serverfault. I would guess you are using a Unix-like OS. In that case, a soft link might do what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly expand on Jamie Wong's response:

You can easily do this using a PHP file acting as a controller - but you must also remember to send the correct content headers otherwise the browser might not recognised the CSS for what it is.

You also need a bit of security checks to make sure there's no file traversal

```
// /public_html/style.php

$cssDir = realname(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../css/';

if (!isset($_GET['sheet'])) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
  exit;
}

$file = realpath($cssDir . $_GET['sheet'] . '.css');
if (!$file) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
  exit;
}

if (substr($file, 0, strlen($cssDir) != $cssDir) {
  // because we've sanitized using realpath - this must match
  header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); // or 403 if you really want to - maybe log it in errors as an attack?
  exit;
}

header('Content-type: text/css');
echo file_get_contents($file);
exit;
```

You can go further than this, and set up .htaccess rewrites to map CSS requests like /css/main.css to this controller:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^css/(*.).css$ /style.php?sheet=$1 [L]
```

Comment: +1 For the mod_rewrite. Always meant to look into how to do that, but never bothered since I learned rails.

Comment: Rewrite is the way forward, although instead of file_get_contents ill probably just include. Thanks

Comment: true - the use of include allows you to use PHP code in the 'stylesheet' so you can set up parameterised colours and so on (something lacking in CSS)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a kind of awkward manner by having a proxy that grabs the files for you.

You could have a php file that acts as a placeholder for these scripts like so:

`www.example.com/style.php?sheet=main`

that reads a file you have in

`/home/your_user/main.css`

through `file_get_contents`

**WARNING**

Be *very* sure that the style.php script doesn't have access to anything outside the folder you specify. This is can be a massive security hole

Answer (score 0):

different domain/website will work.
it's impossible for the web server to give out something that is not in the public folder.. you might want to create a virtual host

Comment: with Apache rewrite module and proper controller logic, you can do this easily

Answer (score 0):

JS and CSS files would be requested by the web browser. In otherwords, the browser has no understanding of your server directory structure...it just needs a valid URI.

Easiest solution would be to set up a subdomain: mycdn.example.com and put your JS and CSS files there and have each site reference that directly.